# Linking edittext to a button

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to know how to link a button to edittext so that anytime a certain id is put on the edittext and a button is press, it send you to another page and give detail information about that I'd. I am a beginner so help me pls.

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need I'd of Edittext or you want to send some data(EditText entered data) from one activity to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file, you need to have [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) and [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) like the following,

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/txt"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="Submit" />
```

And your code should be like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Initialize edittext and button
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    // Set listener to the button
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String text = txt.getText().toString();
             yourFunction(text);
        }
    });
}

private void yourFunction(String text) {
    // Your search code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks boss, I am trying my best as I said I am a beginner so patients with me .

Comment: Sure. You can begin with this and try to implement what you need to do. If you get any issue or find any difficulty while implementing you can post here with what you have tried, and then we can help you to fix that issue.

Comment: <string-array name="numbers">
        <item>39194</item>
        <item>37487</item>
        <item>inpr</item>
        <item>43135</item>
        <item>39749</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: <string-array name="items">
        <item>Sgt Collins</item>
        <item>Sgt Gilbert</item>
        <item>Inpr Kumah</item>
        <item>Cpl Essando</item>
        <item>Sgt Agyare</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: <string-array name="descriptions">
        <item>Mttd personnel at zongo mttd Kumasi</item>
        <item>Mttd personnel at zongo mttd Kumasi</item>
        <item>Mttd personnel at zongo mttd Kumasi</item>
        <item>Mttd personnel at zongo mttd Kumasi</item>
        <item>Mttd personnel at zongo mttd Kumasi</item>

Comment: Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
        numbers = res.getStringArray(R.array.numbers);
        descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items, numbers, descriptions);
        myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

Comment: myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent showDetailActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                showDetailActivity.putExtra("com.manhyia.zongomttdpersonnel.ITEM_INDEX", i);
                startActivity(showDetailActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}

Comment: how can i link all these to edit text so that anytime i put id like 39194 on edittext and press a button it takes me to a page and show detail information about that id?

Comment: @KwakuOsei Tell me what are you trying to do? What is this list for? What details do you need to show when button clicked? Need to filter the list according to user input?

Comment: I want to create an app for my office with edittext and button so that anytime a personnel id  is put on edittext and a button is click, it will bring all the information about that particular id. Thanks for having time for me

Comment: @KwakuOsei Do you need to get data from the database? (MySQL) [Here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-mysql-database-android/) is a nice tutorial. Check how he did that and try to implement it according to your scenario. If you got any query feel free to ask.